# Is ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT redundant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, constraint, check-constraints

I created a table with a foreign key constraint on it. When I generate a table creation script through SSMS, it creates the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MainTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MainTable_ForeignKeyTable] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Field])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ForeignKeyTable] ([PK_Field])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MainTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MainTable_ForeignKeyTable]
GO
```

Since the first statement creates the constraint WITH CHECK, does this make the second statement redundant? If not, what is the CHECK CONSTRAINT accomplishing that the WITH CHECK does not?

I saw [ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/alter-table-check-constraint), but in that case, the SSMS is generating the first statement WITH NOCHECK, so it makes sense to have both statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first statement alters the table to add the constraint.  The second statement *enables or disables* the constraint for future inserts or updates.

So, `ALTER TABLE ... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...` enables the constraint for future inserts/updates.  If you specify `ALTER TABLE ... NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ...`, that *disables* the constraint, thereby allowing future inserts and updates to succeed even if the column in the table referenced by the foreign key does not contain a matching value.  You can see the utility of having both statements present through this example:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.b', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.b;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.a', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.a;

CREATE TABLE dbo.a
(
    a_ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT a_primary_key
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , SomeData varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO dbo.a (a_ID, SomeData)
VALUES (1, 'aaaa')
    , (2, 'bbbb')
    , (3, 'cccc');

CREATE TABLE dbo.b
(
    b_ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT b_primary_key
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , SomeData varchar(10) NOT NULL
    , a_ID int NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO dbo.b (b_ID, SomeData, a_ID)
VALUES (49, 'dddd', 1)
    , (50, 'eeee', 2)
    , (51, 'ffff', 3);
```

So, we created two tables that do not have a defined relationship.  Later, we decide we want to design-in the relationship, so we add a foreign key in `dbo.b` that references the primary key column in `dbo.a`.  We want the existing rows to be checked for validity, but don't care about new rows that might get added in future<sup>1</sup>.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.b 
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT b_a_foreign_key
FOREIGN KEY (a_ID)
REFERENCES a(a_ID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.b 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT b_a_foreign_key;
```

All good.  The existing rows were validated, and new rows *won't* be validated against the foreign key:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.b (b_ID, SomeData, a_ID)
VALUES (52, 'gggg', 4);
```

The table contents:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.b
    LEFT JOIN dbo.a ON b.a_ID = a.a_ID
```

Results:

```
╔══════╦══════════╦══════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ b_ID ║ SomeData ║ a_ID ║ a_ID ║ SomeData ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════╬══════╬══════════╣
║   49 ║ dddd     ║    1 ║ 1    ║ aaaa     ║
║   50 ║ eeee     ║    2 ║ 2    ║ bbbb     ║
║   51 ║ ffff     ║    3 ║ 3    ║ cccc     ║
║   52 ║ gggg     ║    4 ║ NULL ║ NULL     ║  <-- crazy stuff
╚══════╩══════════╩══════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

So, since the code that scripts tables in SSMS has to cover every eventuality, it spits out a `ALTER TABLE ... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...` even if it's not required, and in the vast majority of cases is certainly not required.

---

<sup>1 - why anyone would want existing rows to be validated, but not care about new rows is a little mysterious, but there you go.</sup>

Comment: Related q: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167861/what-is-a-with-check-check-constraint/167866#167866